# How to run a Python script in something other than cmd?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, window

I have written a program. I don't know if it is important how it is written but you can find it here: http://pastebin.com/Z3ZvVPV8 Basically, it asks you to assign values to variables and will perform calculations depending on what variables you chose, and prints the answer.

I would like to know how I can make the program run in a window other than cmd (I am using Windows Vista 32bit). I don't need much at all in terms of GUI, just a window that is a bit more user friendly/easier to look at when they are using the program.

EDIT: To those suggesting using IDLE, while that would work for me, if others want to use the program they would have to download it, so I was hoping for a way for that not to happen.

Comment: You can execute the script from Python's IDLE. I do my coding and execution from it, and it is far easier on the eyes than the cmd.

Comment: But I want other people to be able to run this program, so they would have to install IDLE first

Comment: In that case, I think your best bet might be to code a simple GUI to accept inputs and output the results.

Comment: Any tips on where to start with that?

Answer (score 4):

Python comes with a sort of default GUI package [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) you can use it.
Also there is [a lot of other GUI packages available](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Comment: PyQt and similar alternatives are worth investigating, as Tkinter is poorly documented and not widely used.

Answer (score 1):

The Python standard library offers a lot of ways to implemt simple (but also rather complex) GUIs. I'd like to point you at the documentation of TK (tool kit for graphical interfaces) http://docs.python.org/library/tk.html where you will find also some useful example of use.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is a viable option if you really don't need a gui.  This will make it run and look like a command prompt, but it will be an .exe file.  Here is a quick quote from thier page: "py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation."
2. Another alternative is to get [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/).  Here is a quote from thier webpage: "Portable Python is a  Python® programming language preconfigured to run directly from any USB storage device, enabling you to have, at any time, a portable programming environment. Just download it, extract to your portable storage device or hard drive and in 10 minutes you are ready to create your next Python® application." After packaging the portable python and your .py or .pyc file then create a .bat file that runs the portable python "Python-Portable.exe" with the correct command line parameters for loading your script. Be sure to use relative paths in the batch file in case they are running it from a flash drive, or something other than the same location as you.

NOTE: This is really not a good way to do this as thier download page states: "Installed size: based on selected packages, between 49MB and 480MB".  Also be sure to read the the current Python Software Foundation License, as that is what Portable Python is released under, and it may or may not be legal to package it in a closed source project.  I haven't really looked at the license myself to be able to tell you.  If you are releasing it as open source, then there would not be an issue though.  As a quick side note, if you need that .bat file to be a .exe file then you can use a .bat to .exe converter battoexe.com is one.  This is really going the long way about doing the whole thing, but it is an option.

---

Sources:

Working with Python on and off for 7 years now, a lot that using a portable version on a flash drive, and also dealing with Batch files much longer.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to folow way 2 and have a batch file opening portable python but it opens with the blank Module 1 script. Now that Portable Python has been discontinued it is hard to fine instructions, do you know what the command line parametors are to actualy open the file instead of just portable python?